# Numbers game in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting started with Python, and I have tried to make a "number guessing game". You have 6 guesses between 1 and 100.

The program will tell you of you are way to high, way to lo or close.

My issue is with the end of the game. I can only get my system to deliver a single message.

So the same message appears if you win or loose the game. Please finde the entire below. I appreciate your help.

```
import random
guesses = 6
number = random.randint(0,100)
win = True

while guesses > 0:
    guess = int(input("guess: "))

    guesses -= 1

    if guess == number:
        win == True
        guesses = 0
    elif abs(guess - number) < 4:
        print("You are very close..", guesses, "guesses remaining")
    elif guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too high!", guesses, "guesses remaining")
    elif guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too low!", guesses, "guesses remaining")

if win == True:
    print("Sorry loser!")
else:
    print("Great. You won. Big deal.")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post your actual code, not a picture of it, and please review how to ask a questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks @GerryMcBride
Will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `win` to `True` *initially*, it should be set ot `False` before the loop starts.

```
win = False # line 4
```

Although, you do not need a `win` flag at all. In Python, you can use `while-else` and `for-else` statements. The `else` being executed only if you did not break out of your loop, you can run the losing code there.

Is is more natural to use `break` to get out of a loop than to manually set the condition to a falsy state.

```
import random
number = random.randint(0, 100)

for guesses in range(6, 0, -1):
    guess = int(input("guess: "))

    if guess == number:
        print("Great. You won. Big deal.")
        break
    elif abs(guess - number) < 4:
        print("You are very close..", guesses - 1, "guesses remaining")
    elif guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too high!", guesses - 1, "guesses remaining")
    elif guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too low!", guesses - 1, "guesses remaining")
else:
    print("Sorry loser!")
```

Comment: This is Amazing. Thank you so very much for the great and detailed feedback.